# Does euclid's proof of infinitude of primes generate all the primes if you keep adding the new primes to the list?

Tags: prime-numbers

If I start with a set of consecutive primes, let's say $\{2,3,5,7\}$. Consider $2\times 3\times5\times7+ 1 = 211$. Now, $211$ is prime, so I add it to the set: $\{2,3,5,7,211\}$. If the resulting number is not prime, add the prime divisors of this number which are not in the set.

Just out of curiosity, does this generate all primes for any given starting set? If true, how can you prove that?

Comment: I believe this is an open problem, but I might be wrong.   See the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124039/how-many-primes-does-euclids-proof-account-for).  The usual construction only adds the *smallest* prime obtained by Euclid's construction, not all the primes.  So...maybe the broader problem is known?

Comment: Heuristically , eventually every prime should appear since it is reasonable to assume that the remainder modulo some prime $p$ is random , so we should have a $\frac{1}{p}$-chance to hit some given prime. This is of cours no proof and I strongly doubt there is one. There is a very similar problem for which it is unknown whether every prime appears.

Comment: Note that we will sooner or later hit a "brickwall" , a number too difficult to be factored in practice.